# Mutiple select, tried val(), can't get values

Tags: jquery, multiple-select

So I've read the other question about this and I can't seem to get it to work.
I have this HTML:

```
    <select name="filter" id="filter" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
    <option>Choose Filter</option>
    <option value="Matt"> Matt</option>
    <option value="Brian"> Brian </option>
    </select>
```

Yet using this code:

```
    $("#filter").val()
```

Returns me an empty string, even when options are selected.

Comment: Lol you know it was an easy solution when 4 answers pop up immediately. For the record, using my suggestion will also grab html line breaks if you need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#filter').change(function(){
    var selectedValues = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function(){
                             return this.value;
                         }).get();
    console.log(selectedValues);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fCLjt/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Comment: My absolute pleasure; I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('option:selected','#filter').html()
```

Comment: This returns the HTML content, not the option values. In his example they happen to be the same, but they usually aren't.

Comment: @barmar good point actually. I only looked at how his was written. I use .html() often when I need to capture html carriage returns. But val html text innerHTM etc...use whatever.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 $("#filter option:selected").val();
```

Comment: Hmm, this will only return the topmost selected value when both are selected.